# org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: Premature end of file

Tags: api, mule, gateway

I am using mule API gateway , I have deployed my package in it. But in API gateway that 
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: Premature end of file.

I have tried in version 1.3.0 and 3.8.0. In both I got same error.

Please help me.

File :

```
<http:connector name="httpConnector" />

<esper:config name="esperModule" configuration="esper-config.xml" />

<mxml:dom-to-xml-transformer name="domToXmlTransformer" />

<flow name="websocket-esper-bridge">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="niohttp://localhost:8080/websocket/events"
        exchange-pattern="one-way">
        <http:websocket path="events" />
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <custom-processor
        class="com.mulesoft.demo.mule.websocket.EsperWebSocketUpdateListener">
        <spring:property name="esperModule" ref="esperModule" />
        <spring:property name="httpConnector" ref="httpConnector" />
        <spring:property name="domToXmlTransformer" ref="domToXmlTransformer" />
    </custom-processor>
</flow>

<flow name="signupEventsGenerator">
    <poll frequency="3000">
        <set-payload value="&lt;signup id='fake' /&gt;"/>
    </poll>

    <mxml:xml-to-dom-transformer returnClass="org.w3c.dom.Document" />
    <esper:send eventName="SignupEvent" eventPayload-ref="#[message.payload]" />
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a current known issue with 3.8.0. The error is not very descriptive but it means you are missing a schema declaration for a component. Could you post the entire XML file contents? It's probably one you're using, like http, esper, mxml.
HTH

Comment: <mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/nio-http"
    xmlns:mxml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
    xmlns:esper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/esper"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

Comment: xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
            http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/nio-http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/nio-http/current/mule-nio-http.xsd
            http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/3.3/mule-xml.xsd
            http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/esper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/esper/current/mule-esper.xsd

Comment: http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            ">

Comment: Above is the schema of the XML file.

Comment: Actuality I am trying to configure websocket API in mule API gateway. Please  help to solve API gateway configuration for websocket API.

Comment: Using above xml I am not able configure websocket API in gateway.

Comment: You can edit your original post with the data. The limit of the comment section makes this really hard to understand.